# Tcsh Script Last Exit Code ($?) value is resetting

Tags: shell, tcsh

I am running the following script using tcsh. In my while loop, I'm running a C++ program that I created and will return a different exit code depending on certain things. While it returns an exit code of 0, I want the script to increment counter and run the program again.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

echo "Starting the script."
set counter = 0

while ($? == 0)
    @ counter ++
    ./auto $counter
end
```

I have verified that my program is definitely returning with exit code = 1 after a certain point. However, the condition in the while loop keeps evaluating to true for some reason and running.

I found that if I stick the following line at the end of my loop and then replace the condition check in the while loop with this new variable, it works fine.

```
while ($return_code == 0)
    @ counter ++
    ./auto $counter
    set return_code = $?
end
```

Why is it that I can't just use $? directly? Is another operation underneath the hood performed in between running my custom program and checking the loop condition that's causing $? to change value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is peculiar.

I've altered your example to something that I think illustrates the issue more clearly.  (Note that `$?` is an alias for `$status`.)

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

foreach i (1 2 3)
    false
    # echo false status=$status
end
echo Done status=$status
```

The output is

```
Done status=0
```

If I uncomment the `echo` command in the loop, the output is:

```
false status=1
false status=1
false status=1
Done status=0
```

(Of course the `echo` in the loop would break the logic anyway, because the `echo` command completes successfully and sets `$status` to zero.)

I *think* what's happening is that the `end` that terminates the loop is executed as a statement, and it sets `$status` (`$?`) to 0.

I see the same behavior with both `tcsh` and `bsd-csh`.

Saving the value of `$status` in another variable immediately after the command is a good workaround -- and arguably just a better way of doing it, since `$status` is extremely fragile, and will almost literally be clobbered if you look at it.

Note that I've add a `-f` option to the `#!` line.  This prevents `tcsh` from sourcing your init file(s) (`.cshrc` or `.tcshrc`) and is considered good practice. (That's not the case for sh/bash/ksh/zsh, which assign a completely different meaning to `-f`.)

A digression: I used `tcsh` regularly for many years, both as my interactive login shell and for scripting. I would not have anticipated that `end` would set `$status`. This is not the first time I've had to find out how `tcsh` or `csh` behaves by trial and error and been surprised by the result. It is one of the reasons I switched to `bash` for interactive and scripting use. I won't tell you to do the same, but you might want to read Tom Christiansen's classic "[csh.whynot](https://web.mit.edu/daveg/Info/csh.whynot)".

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter/simpler explanation:

Recall that with tcsh/csh EACH command (including shell builtin) return a status. Therefore $? (aliases to $status) is updated by 'if' statements, 'for' loops, assignments, ...

From practical point of view, better to limit the usage of direct use of $? to an if statement after the command execution:

```
do-something
if ( $status == 0 )
   ...
endif
```

In all other cases, capture the status in a variable, and use only that variable

```
do-something
something_status=$?
if ( $something_status == 0 )
   ...
endif
```

To expand on the $status, even a condition test in an if statement will modify the status, therefore the following repeated test on $status will not never hit the '$status == 5', even when do-something will return status of 5

```
do-something
if ( $status == 2 ) then
  echo FOO
else if ( $status == 5 ) then
  echo BAR
endif
```